# appears border at the top of my footer active tab on android

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm doing my ionic mobile application, everything looks good, but when i'm testing my app on android, appears border at the top of my footer active tab, like on photo [image]

i tried to set border-top: 0px, border: 0px, border: none, to every element of this tabs navigation, but it appers anyway, how to fix it?

Here is my menu.html:

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top" id="tab">

  <ion-tab title="Feed" icon-off="my-feed-icon" icon-on="my-yellow-feed-icon"
    href="#/app/feed">
    <ion-nav-view name="feed-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Selected" icon-off="my-selected-icon" icon-on="my-yellow-selected-icon"
    href="#/app/selected">
    <ion-nav-view name="selected-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Actions" icon-off="my-actions-icon" icon-on="my-yellow-actions-icon"
    href="#/app/actions">
    <ion-nav-view name="actions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Charts" icon-off="my-charts-icon" icon-on="my-yellow-charts-icon"
    href="#/app/charts">
    <ion-nav-view name="charts-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="More" icon="my-more-icon"
    href="#/app/more">
    <ion-nav-view name="more-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>  

</ion-tabs>
```

And example on http://play.ionic.io/app/2d5464658b7e, but you can see this only on android/

Comment: Try this: 
border-top: 0px !important

Comment: Can you create a demo: http://play.ionic.io/ ?

Comment: Can show your tab.html page?

Answer (score 0):

So, ran into this and figured out it's unanswered so I inspected in chrome and found out how to achieve this, if someone else needs it sometimes here it is:

```
.tabs-striped.tabs-light .tab-item.tab-item-active,
.tabs-striped.tabs-light .tab-item.active,
.tabs-striped.tabs-light .tab-item.activated .list select {
    border:none;
}
```

Just replace the **tabs-light** with whatever tabs template you're using ....